# Multiple span tags under a div add extra spaces

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a typography animation, and in that regard, I have all the characters of the text in a `<span>` tag as shown below.

But, the output of the html is as shown in the image below, with extra spaces between my span elements. (Notice one extra element shown between each span)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
   

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-row">
        <span>W</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>P</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>v</span>
        <span>i</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: `inline` elements respect the whitespace between it and other `inline` elements. If you remove the whitespace/linebreaks in the source between each of the `span`s the whitespace in the final output will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because span is an inline element. If you want to get rid if the white spaces use float property for the span items

```
span {
    float: left;
}
```

Go through the below source to explore more about display properties -
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: no need the display:block with float

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for correcting.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.container .text .text-row span {
  
float: left;
   
  
}
```

```html
   

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text">
      <div class="text-row">
        <span>W</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>P</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>v</span>
        <span>i</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.text span {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 900;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="text">
    <div class="text-row">
      <span>W</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span>&nbsp;</span>
      <span>P</span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>v</span>
      <span>i</span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span>e</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will fix your problem